# on('click') doesn't work after off('click')

Tags: jquery

The following code doesn't work. It removes class disabled, but the divs are not again clickable. I mean function works only once.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('div.downloadbutton').on('click', function(e) {
         $('div.downloadbutton').off('click');
         $('div.downloadbutton').not(this).addClass('disabled', {duration:500});

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('div.downloadbutton').on('click');
             $('div.downloadbutton').not(this).removeClass('disabled', {duration:500});
        }, 3000);
     });
});
```

Comment: You still need to provide a function to `on('click')` - it will not just replace the previously attached event handler.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted? You gave an explanation of the issue, and your code... what more do people want?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i don't understand it at all. so how can I make this example working? / Well, the question might be for people too stupid to ask here..

Comment: Have you considered writing the `click` callback as a named function so that you simply call it `.on('click', fn)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than binding/unbinding event handlers, try having a state variable which you can control the logic with. Something like this:

```
var clickDisabled = false; // initial state; allow the click

$('div.downloadbutton').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!clickDisabled) {
        $('div.downloadbutton').not(this).addClass('disabled', { duration:500 });
        clickDisabled = true;
        setTimeout(function() { clickDisabled = false; }, 3000);
     };
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wQZ3T/)